# How can I lift the grid above the mesh itself for the car roof like it is on the car hood? Or just make the grid see-able through it somehow?

Tags: modeling, mesh, 3d-view, edit-mode, visibility

How can I lift the grid above the mesh itself for the car roof like it is on the car hood? Or just make the grid see-able through it somehow? It is quite difficult currently to for example select the necessary vertices.

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: X-ray mode - Alt + Z

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**EDIT**:  I see you're looking to see the "grid" of mesh verts through another one, not the global cardinal grids.  As answered above, use x-ray mode.
I would add to this, try checking "wireframe" *on* in "Overlays" and adjust the opacity to your liking.]

---

---

I'm assuming you just need visual representation of parallel lines at even intervals.   This solution is a little bit old-school, but it's guaranteed to work and might be useful to someone in a similar situation.

---

[image]
You could create a plane and do a simple subdivide...

---

[image]
Set the viewport display to "Wire"

---

[image]
Now you have a portable grid that you can move/rotate (or scale) this piece of geometry exactly where you need it.

---

Answer (score 1):

X-ray helped (alt + z), but the problem was i had extruded a single vertice, which seems to bug blender out.